# how to calculate the time and space complexity of this nested recursive function

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space-complexity

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int n)
{
 if(n>100)
 return n-10;
 return fun(fun(n+11));
}
int main()
{
 int r;
 r=fun(95);
 printf("%d\n",r);
 return 0;
}
```

the answer says time complexity is O(n), can anyone explain how?

Comment: When in doubt pop a counter in, run with a series of different Ns, and plot the results.

Comment: it's constant time, because there is always the upper limit of recursive calls (not dependent on n) for any n<=100 (we don't care about other values of n since they return immediately)

Comment: `O(n)` That might be an answer to a different question than asked here. @mangusta The [McCarthy 91 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthy_91_function) is well defined for negative `n`, too. It does in fact evaluate to a constant, but the recursion is not O(1) for negative values.

Comment: @dxiv yep, for negative values of n, the number of recursions will be proportional to n itself